# How to make a table fit page size?

Tags: tables, page

I would like to make a table fit the paperwidth=16cmx24cm I have set. How to do that please? Thanks. Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
            \hline
            $Q$ $\ast$& $\Sigma$ $\rightarrow \Gamma$ &  & $\ast (R/L)$ & $Q$ \\
            \hline
            \lipsum \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Edited after Mico comment**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}

        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
                        \hline
                        $Q$ $\ast$& $\Sigma$ $\rightarrow \Gamma$ &  & $\ast (R/L)$ & $Q$ \\
                        \hline
                        When we stand on a particular state $Q$ & and we have to read a symbole as input & we write someting ont the tape $\Gamma$ & and we move left/on the tape & and we get to the next state. \\
                        \hline
        \end{tabular*}

        \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|r|r|r|r|r|}
                        \hline
                        $Q$ $\ast$& $\Sigma$ $\rightarrow \Gamma$ &  & $\ast (R/L)$ & $Q$ \\
                        \hline
                        When we stand on a particular state $Q$ & and we have to read a symbole as input & we write someting ont the tape $\Gamma$ & and we move left/on the tape & and we get to the next state. \\
                        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If a table has to have a certain width, don't use `tabular`. Instead, use either `tabular*` or `tabularx`. Which one of these two to employ depends importantly on the *contents* of the table. You're not really looking to typeset several paragraphs of lipsum gibberish, are you? Incidentally, is there a reason for writing `$Q$ $\ast$` and `$\Sigma$ $\rightarrow \Gamma$` instead of `$Q \ast$` and `$\Sigma \rightarrow \Gamma$`?

Comment: Mico, getting the same result with both environment tabular* and tabularx. Question above has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote in an earlier comment:

> If a table has to have a certain width, don't use `tabular`. Instead, use either `tabular*` or `tabularx`. Which one of these two to employ depends importantly on the *contents* of the table.

Since the table in your addendum requires line-breaking, you shouldn't be using `tabular*` environment. Focus on getting the `tabularx` syntax straight. In particular, one or more columns of a `tabularx` environment *must* be of type `X`. (Do please study the user guide of the `tabularx` environment for more information.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{|*{5}{R|}}
    \hline
    $Q \ast$& $\Sigma \rightarrow \Gamma$ &  & $\ast (R/L)$ & $Q$ \\
    \hline
    When we stand on a particular state~$Q$ & and we have to read a symbole as input & we write someting ont the tape $\Gamma$ & and we move left/on the tape & and we get to the next state. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```